# Equivalente de BitConverter en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy con un problema, en `C#` hice la siguiente función, pero al intentar pasar el programa a `C++` con el IDE Qt5.7 encuentro el problema que `BitConverter` es palabra reservada de `C#`

```
short ConvertBytesToShort(byte msb, byte lsb){
if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
   return BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[2] {(byte)lsb , (byte)msb }, 0);
else
   return BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[2] {(byte)msb , (byte)lsb }, 0);
}
```

Comment: *`BitConverter` es palabra reservada de [tag:C#]*, No, `BitConverter` no es palabra reservada, es una clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumiblemente el estándar C++20 incorporará en `type_traits` funcionalidad para diferenciar las arquitecturas.

En ese caso tu código C++ podría lucir más o menos así:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

uint16_t ConvertBytesToShort(uint8_t msb, uint8_t lsb)
{
  if( std::endian::native == std::endian::big )
    return (static_cast<uint16_t>(lsb) << 8) + msb;
  else if( std::endian::native == std::endian::little )
     return (static_cast<uint16_t>(msb) << 8) + lsb;
  else
    // te faltaria tratar este caso
}
```

Mientras esperamos los 3 años que quedan hasta que este estándar vea la luz puedes usar un apaño tal que:

**C++17**

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr bool is_big_endian()
{
  union
  {
    uint32_t intDummy;
    unsigned char c[4];
  } uTest = { 0x01020304 };

  return uTest.c[0] == 1; 
}

uint16_t ConvertBytesToShort(uint8_t msb, uint8_t lsb){
  if( is_big_endian() )
     return (static_cast<uint16_t>(lsb) << 8) + msb;
  else
     return (static_cast<uint16_t>(msb) << 8) + lsb;
}
```

**C++11 y anteriores**

```
#include <cstdint>

bool is_big_endian()
{
  union
  {
    uint32_t intDummy;
    unsigned char c[4];
  } uTest = { 0x01020304 };

  return uTest.c[0] == 1; 
}

uint16_t ConvertBytesToShort(uint8_t msb, uint8_t lsb){
  if( is_big_endian() )
     return (static_cast<uint16_t>(lsb) << 8) + msb;
  else
     return (static_cast<uint16_t>(msb) << 8) + lsb;
}
```