# BitConverter.ToInt16 y ToInt32 en C++

Tags: c#, c++, bitconverter

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código en C#

```
int offset = BitConverter.ToInt16(_signData, 28) + 32;
offset += BitConverter.ToInt32(_signData, offset);
byte[] hash2Data = new byte[_signData.Length - offset];
Array.Copy(_signData, offset, hash2Data, 0, hash2Data.Length);
```

Entiendo en gran medida lo que hace, aunque emplee algunos números "mágicos", pero trato de hacer lo mismo en `C++`. El problema viene por la clase BitConverter que no tiene un equivalente directo en `C++`. He mirado otras soluciones como [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90807/equivalente-de-bitconverter-en-c?newreg=c643bb45b3444641826c2c8b3d52ef5e) y [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255229/c-equivalent-of-bitconverter) pero no me han servido por la parte en que `ToInt16` y `ToInt32` te dan la opción de introducir una posición concreta del `array`. Soy relativamente nuevo en `C++` y esto me está despistando ¿alguna idea?. Gracias.

P.d.: siento la falta de etiquetas pero no tengo privilegios para agregar como etiquetas `BitConverter` o `ToInt16`

EDIT: Gracias por las respuestas y es cierto que se me pasó incluir más código. Este es el código que he implementado pero que me da problemas incluso con debug (un error que cierra la aplicación).

```
    int offset = *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(pbtSignData+28)+32;
    int arraysize = offset + *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(pbtSignData+offset);       
    BYTE* hash2data = new byte[nSize_signdata - arraysize];
    std::copy(pbtSignData + offset, pbtSignData + (nSize_signdata - arraysize), hash2data);
    BYTE* hash2;
    SHA256(hash2data, nSize_signdata - arraysize,hash2);

    std::ofstream outhash2("C:/Users/IEUser/Downloads/hash2.txt");
    outhash2 << hash2;
    outhash2.close();
```

EDIT 2:
Implementé ambas soluciones proporcionadas pero sin éxito, o eso creía. Con otra ayuda implementé lo siguiente, que se parece bastante al código original pero "traducido" a C++:

```
int nOffset = *((short*)(&pbtSignData[28])) + 32;
nOffset += *((int*)(&pbtSignData[nOffset]));
BYTE* pbtHash2Data = new BYTE[nSize_signdata - nOffset];        
memcpy(pbtHash2Data, &pbtSignData[nOffset], nSize_signdata - nOffset);
```

El problema resulta que es el mismo que con las otras soluciones implementadas: `nOffset` recoge unos valores absurdos muy elevados y provoca fallo en la declaración de `pbtHash2Data` o `violation memory access` en `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente no se suelen responder a preguntas que no muestran código.

Entiendo que, por las búsquedas que has hecho, al menos has intentado hacer algo.

Una posible solución:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace BitConverter
{
  template<class T>
  std::string ToInt16(T const& element, size_t start = 0)
  {
    std::stringstream ss;
    unsigned char const* ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(&element) + start;
    for(size_t i=start; i<sizeof(element); ++i, ++ptr)
    {
      if( i != start )
        ss << '-';
      ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(*ptr);
    }

    return ss.str();
  }
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SJ7nKU0OgnSl5Fao).

Es una solución rápida que no tiene en cuenta, por ejemplo, si el sistema es bigendian o little endian, algo que afectaría al resultado final.

---

Como parece que lo que necesitas es la representación entera, con los cambios quedaría así:

```
namespace BitConverter
{
  template<class Input>
  std::vector<unsigned> ToInt16(Input const& element, size_t start = 0)
  {
    std::vector<unsigned> toReturn;
    unsigned char const* ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(&element) + start;
    for(size_t i=start; i<sizeof(element); ++i, ++ptr)
    {
      toReturn.push_back(static_cast<unsigned>(*ptr));
    }

    return toReturn;
  }
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jJOuzzktEDnTLyzF).

> EDIT 2: Implementé ambas soluciones proporcionadas pero sin éxito, o eso creía. Con otra ayuda implementé lo siguiente, que se parece bastante al código original pero "traducido" a C++:

Piensa que nosotros **no sabemos** qué representan esos números mágicos, luego no los podemos integrar en nuestras soluciones porque no podemos garantizar que su aplicación sea la correcta. Esa parte corre de tu cuenta.

Comment: Soy consciente de ello, yo tampoco sé el porqué de los números mágicos. En resumen debería coger ciertas posiciones del array, pasarlas a int y con ello construir otro array que contenga parte del original. Sin embargo los valores recogidos para tomarlos como índices son absurdos y aún no entiendo el porqué. De todas maneras gracias por la ayuda :).

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien la documentación de [`ToInt16`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint16?view=netframework-4.7.2) y [`ToInt32`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.2), estas funciones leen respectivamente dos y cuatro bytes para crear respectivamente un valor de 16 y 32 bits. QUe yo sepa, no existe un equivalente estándar en C++ de dichas funciones, pero puedes crear una plantilla:

```
template <typename return_t, typename iterator_t>
return_t convierte(iterator_t begin, iterator_t end)
{
    return_t resultado{};

    // Solo valido para tipos aritmeticos, en caso contrario lanza excepcion.
    if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<return_t>)
    {
        constexpr auto tamanyo = sizeof(return_t);
        auto elementos = std::distance(begin, end);

        // El tipo resultante debe tener tantos bytes como elementos proveidos
        if (elementos == tamanyo)
        {
            for (int shift = 8 * (tamanyo - 1); begin != end; ++begin, shift -= 8)
            {
                resultado |= (*begin << shift);
            }
        }
        else
            throw std::length_error{"Tamanyo incorrecto"};
    }
    else
        throw std::invalid_argument{"Tipo incorrecto"};

    return resultado;
}
```

El uso de la plantilla anterior es el siguiente:

```
constexpr unsigned char datos[]{0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0x40, 0x50, 0x60, 0x70, 0x80};
auto a = convierte<int>(datos, datos + 4);
auto b = convierte<unsigned int>(datos + 4, datos + 8);
auto c = convierte<short>(datos, datos + 2);
auto d = convierte<unsigned short>(datos + 2, datos + 4);

auto muestra = [](auto valor) { std::cout << std::dec << valor << " = " << std::hex << valor << '\n'; };
muestra(a);
muestra(b);
muestra(c);
muestra(d);
```

El código anterior muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 270544960 = 10203040
> 1348497536 = 50607080
> 4128 = 1020
> 12352 = 3040
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IoHwLPFzZicdzeWT).

Comment: Gracias pero me da un error:
Error C4984 'if constexpr' is a C++17 language extension

Comment: Usa un compilador compatible con C++17 o acmbia el `if constexpr` por un `if`.